# How to check the balance of the list of 1 million Bitcoin Addresses?

Tags: blockchain, wallet, address, api, balance

How to check the balance of the list of 1 million Bitcoin Addresses? Is there such a program?

Answer (score 1):

[Insight Block Explorer](https://insight.is/) is the program.   It has an API you can query.

You'll need to install the block explorer.  It runs in a nodejs environment.

Comment: Please tell me how to work with "Insight Block Explorer"?

Comment: It is a full stack application.   You have to enable zmq on your bitcoin node, and then the bitcore internals allow for fast access to blockchain data by it's API.

It's quite a lengthy process to install it.   The version I've used most recently requires nodejs v4 which is quite old.  Sorry I can't be much help - I use it with non-bitcoin environments (other blockchains).

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a bitcoin full node, then create a program to scan from latest block to first block all the unspent outputs and keep in memory, maybe in something like Redis, the status of the balances of the addresses until you reach the 1 million you are looking for